# MS Access: Show entire group, based on another field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I would like to show **all** classes and grades of **only** those students who have at least one "F" grade.

Here is the source table:

```
ID  |  Students  |  Class  |  Grade  
1  |  Addams, W  |  History  |  A  
2  |  Addams, W  |  Biology  |  A  
3  |  Addams, W  |  French  |  B  
4  |  Jetson, E  |  Spanish  |  B  
5  |  Jetson, E  |  Geometry  |  B  
6  |  Jetson, E  |  Biology  |  F  
7  |  Rubble, B  |  English  |  F  
8  |  Rubble, B  |  Geometry  |  B         
9  |  Rubble, B  |  Biology  |  B  
10  |  Flintstone, P  |  Music  |  A  
11  |  Flintstone, P  |  Spanish  |  B
```

Here is a report, grouped by Students:

```
Addams, W  
    ---------------French    B  
    ---------------Biology    A  
    ---------------History     A  
Flintstone, P  
    ---------------Spanish   B  
    ---------------Music      A  
Jetson, E  
    ---------------Biology    F  
    ---------------Geometry  B  
    ---------------Spanish    B  
Rubble, B  
    ---------------Biology     B  
    ---------------Geometry  B  
    ---------------English     F
```

Again, I would like to show **all** classes and grades of **only** those students who have at least one "F" grade, as seen below:

```
Jetson, E  
    ---------------Biology    F  
    ---------------Geometry  B  
    ---------------Spanish    B  
Rubble, B  
    ---------------Biology     B  
    ---------------Geometry  B  
    ---------------English     F
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a query with your table as the source.  Drop in the Students field in the first column and put the following formula in the second column: IIf([Grade]=”F”,1,0), then save the query. (by default Access will name this column “Expr1”, but you change it to whatever you like)
2. Create a 2nd query using query 1 as the source, drop in the 2 columns from query 1, group on, sum the column with the formula, and in this column add a criteria of >=1, and save.  You now have a table with only the students who have at least 1 “F”. (you group on by placing cursor in the grid section of the query at the bottom, right-clicking and selecting "Totals" from the prompt box)
3. Create a 3rd query tying the 2nd query to your original source table by connecting the Students field with a 1 to 1 match (i.e. join type 1).

Answer (score 0):

You can query your table using a subquery to query on the same table for any instances having a F grade:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Students, a.Class, a.Grade
FROM yourtable AS a
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM yourtable AS b
WHERE a.Students = b.Students
AND b.Grade = 'F'
);
```

Next, base your report on above query.

Comment: OP here: This worked beautifully; thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

OP here: Both answers worked; thanks again. Here is the code for the second answer:

Query 1
SELECT Students2.Students, IIf([Grade]="F",1,0) AS F_grade
FROM Students2;

Query 2
SELECT Query1.Students, Sum(Query1.F_grade) AS SumOfF_grade
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Students
HAVING (((Sum(Query1.F_grade))>=1));

Query 3
SELECT Students2.Students, Students2.Class, Students2.Grade
FROM Students2 INNER JOIN Query2 ON Students2.Students = Query2.Students;